# Get value along with String in string.xml file

Tags: java, android, xml

I have the following in my strings.xml file:

```
<resources>
   <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
   <string name="title_activity_maps">Map</string>

   <string-array name="city_names">

      <item value="1452">Abbotsford</item>
      <item value="163">Aberdeen</item>
      <item value="821">Acornhoek</item>
      <item value="168">Addo</item>
      <item value="153">Adelaide</item>
      <item value="1433">Aeroton</item>
      <item value="790">Agatha</item>
      <item value="393">Aggeneys</item>
      <item value="867">Agulhas</item>


   </string-array>
```

I'm using it for an AutoCompleteTextView. My question is, how can I get the value to be printed to the logs after the user searches a city?
I'm using this to get the city names, but also wants the value.

```
cityNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.city_names);
```

Comment: Replace the string array resource with something else, as there is no `value` attribute on `<item>`, according to [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray). You could use an XML resource (`res/xml/`), JSON in an asset, etc. Or, have two `<string-array>` resources, one with the city names and one with the corresponding values. If those values are always going to be integers, you could use [an `<integer-array>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#IntegerArray) if you prefer.

Comment: With the `<string-array>` and `<integer-array>` . How will I link the two together   for it to give me 1452 when the user searched "Abbotsford"?

Comment: "Abbortsford" is the 0th element in the `<string-array>`, so look up the 0th element in the `<integer-array>`. "Addo" is the 4th element in the `<string-array>`, so look up the 4th element in the `<integer-array>`. Or, use the two arrays to build yourself some other in-memory data structure (e.g., `HashMap`).

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done this way and there is no `value` attribute in `<item>` XML tag. What you can do is that you have your string as a pattern and try to parse that pattern in two different values using string manipulation or JSON or any structured data format.

Example:

```
<string-array name="city_names">
   <item>Abbotsford,1452</item>
   <item>Aberdeen,163</item>
</string-array>
```

and then parse that using the `split` on the string to get your two values.